# Parse.com can't get correct username from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am trying to implement Facebook auth with Parse SDK as described in officialy manual.
But instead of real name I am getting some token when calling [PFUser currentUser]

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    if ([PFUser currentUser] && [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
        NSLog(@"USER == %@ == IS ALREADY LINKED WITH FACEBOOK", [PFUser currentUser]);
    }
}
```

NSLOG shows me this: `USER == Op2Qz1RxiwR1zflsSzCVR538A == IS ALREADY LINKED WITH FACEBOOK`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are telling it to log the entire user object. This will probably log something like a unique I'd or something.

If you want the name then you should use...

```
[PFUser currentUser].userName
```

Or some other property.

It doesnt know which part of the user to log unless you actually tell it which part you want to log.

Comment: It's the same. I've checked my parse entity and it's adding to username this token. Maybe I have to check adding new user to Parse.

Comment: Ok. What are you expecting it to display? You could use the fbID property instead. If you want to store the actually users name like "John Doe" then you'll have to manually add this as a new field.

Comment: Yes I need to Store Real user's Full Name.

Comment: If you look at the data online you will see that this isn't stored anywhere. You need to manually get this through a Facebook request against the user and store that in a new field (I think). Just check the actual online data. You will see that the name isn't there.

Comment: Ok I have found the issue. I was adding to [PFUser currentUser] object "name". But I had add it to [PFUser currentUser].username. From now it's showing and adding correct username